# Looker difference between two pivoted columns

Tags: pivot, looker

I’m trying to get the differences between `test` and `control` for segments 1 and 2.

Disregard the values that you see in the `Diff` column. I’m currently using pivot_offset, but that applies to every column.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `if` function to check if the segment is the same, this will return null values into the columns you highlighted in red.

```
if(${view.segment}=pivot_offset(${view.segment},-1),
   ${view.metric}-pivot_offset(${view.metric},-1),
   null)
```